# QuickFIX and MFC: cannot login using Initiatior.logon() function

Tags: c++, mfc, quickfix

I'm developing a GUI application where I try to integrate QuickFIX library into MFC. I have successfully added all the needed libs and includes, however, when I try to connect using the logon() function I am encountering troubles. First of all, the engine starts requiering more fields in the config file, which it doesn't care in a console application. Secondly, after the logon request, I receive "Debug Assertion Failed! Program: C:\Windows\System32\MSVCP120D.DLL   File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtree
Line: 327
Expression: map/set iterators incompatible".
What I am trying to do is as follows:
I have a menu. If you press "Start" in the menu, I set a bool flag to true. In my OnKickIdle function(the application is dialog based) I check this flag, and if it is set - I start the normal initiation of the SockeInitiator. All is OK until I call the logon() function, and after it's call - the debug assertion is thrown. This is the CallStack output:

> msvcp120d.dll!std::_Debug_message(const wchar_t * message, const wchar_t * file, unsigned int line) Line 15 C++
>       OKKOIN_BOT.exe!std::_Tree_const_iterator > > >::operator==(const std::_Tree_const_iterator > > > & _Right) Line 327   C++
>       OKKOIN_BOT.exe!std::_Tree_const_iterator > > >::operator!=(const std::_Tree_const_iterator > > > & _Right) Line 341   C++
>       OKKOIN_BOT.exe!FIX::SocketInitiator::onTimeout(FIX::SocketConnector & __formal) Line 227    C++
>       OKKOIN_BOT.exe!FIX::SocketInitiator::onStart() Line 93  C++
>       OKKOIN_BOT.exe!FIX::Initiator::startThread(void * p) Line 286   C++
>       [External Code]

Have somebody experienced the same issues and tried to integrate QuickFIX into MFC? Thank you so much in advance guys. 
Here is also the part of my OnKickIdle() function:

```
LRESULT COKKOIN_BOTDlg::OnKickIdle(WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
 if (b_startFlag)
 {
    std::string filepath = "quickfix-client.cfg";
    FIX::SessionSettings settings(filepath);
    Application app(settings);
    FIX::FileStoreFactory storefact(settings);
    FIX::ScreenLogFactory logfactory(settings);
    FIX::SocketInitiator initiator(app, storefact, settings, logfactory);
    b_initflag = TRUE;
    //initializing the needed variables 
    initiator.start();     //use poll instead
    Sleep(2000);
    if (initiator.isLoggedOn())
    {
        MessageBox(L"Logged On", L"Information", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox(L"Not Logged On", L"Information", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
 }
return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Debug it, it will be easier that way rather than us trying to guess. And it isn't a quickfix issue, but more of your code.

Comment: Actually I am running it in debug mode, and I cannot understand what creates this issue, because it happens straight after logon() call. I can see where it happens in my code if I run the application in debug mode - but I cannot understand what causes this error.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the issue guys. The problem as in MFC itself because it does not support Windows Sockets 2, which is required by QuickFIX. I suppose the question can be closed.